# django's UserCreationForm problem

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I have got problem with django's UserCreationForm. It's very strange because ween I:

view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

form = UserCreationForm()

context = {'form' : form}

render_to_response('something.html', context)
```

template:

```
...
{% block content %}
{{form}}
{% endblock %}
```

I get:

```
<class 'django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm'>
```

Stuff like {{form.as_table}} or similar doesn't work. "For" tags scream that:

```
aught an exception while rendering: 'ModelFormMetaclass' object is not iterable
```

I don't know where is the problem. I simply can't view in template labels and fields. HELP:p

Comment: Are you **returning** render_to_response? i.e. `return render_to_response('something.html', context)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have missed something in the code.

What must had lead you to this error is:

```
form = UserCreationForm

{% for field in form1 %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
```

Here the error is that you missed the parentheses after `UserCreationForm`

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the code of the view you're actually trying? It seems as if you've written:

```
form = UserCreationForm
```

rather than

```
form = UserCreationForm()
```